# Как работает "^" в питоне?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Увидел, что человек в коде вместо `10**3` писал  `10^3`.
Как бы ошибка очевидна, но я решил проверить, а вообще `10^3` работает ли в коде.
И это работает, но выводит довольно интересные значения.

Поискав в интернете не нашел ничего об этом. Но очень стало интересно, что это такое?

> ```
> In [1]: 10^1
> Out[1]: 11
> In [2]: 10^2
> Out[2]: 8
> In [3]: 10^3
> Out[3]: 9
> In [4]: 10^4
> Out[4]: 14
> In [5]: 10^10
> Out[5]: 0
> In [6]: 10^9
> Out[6]: 3
> ```

Comment: Документация https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types

Comment: Спасибо большое! Обязательно ознакомлюсь! Как то вылетели из головы бинарные операции

Comment: Обозначение x^y для возведения в степень довольно распространено и пришло от математиков пишущих статьи в (La)TeX

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Указанная Вами операция называется "Исключающее ИЛИ". Ещё его называют "Побитовое исключающее ИЛИ" и применяется для манипуляции битами.

Возвращает 1 в каждый бит, где только один из двух сравнимых битов имел значение 1.

Пример:

> 1010 ^ 0100 = 1110

В приведённых Вами примерах указаны числа в десятичной системе. Поэтому при вычислении возвращается десятичное представление.

Comment: Ааа, т.е. идет сравнение по битам и там, где биты отличны возвращается истина, а иначе - ложь.
Понял! Как-то не подумал о битовых операциях!

Comment: @ТотСамый, Именно так. Если мой ответ Вам помог - зачтите его как верный.